# Sudden upvotes burst without increase in total reputation

Tags: support

I just logged in on StackOverflow and saw and this unusual upvotes burst in my history, from approx. 3 hours ago.

I don't remember how many reputation points I had before, but I'm pretty sure it was more than 7k, possibly more than 7.1k. So I'm suspecting that it actually made my reputation decrease (possibly because the 200 points cap). In either way, I don't think it's a natural event.

Did anyone else experience the same problem?

[image: upvotes burst]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: @Rizier123 I would understand if that was the case. The problem is: it seems like all the upvotes from some user were "reapplied" today, because my total reputation didn't seem to change (it decreased a little, at most) and I have no other information in my history other than the upvotes. PS: I hadn't ever before reached the daily cap.

Comment: Your user history says the most your rep has ever been is 6,856, and it had been that way for almost a week prior to this burst of upvotes, so perhaps you misremembered.

Comment: @BoltClock That is possible, there's some time I don't log in on SO to answer questions. Anyway, this seems like a serial voting episode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did get hit with some serial voting, which was reversed a few minutes ago. The 200 rep cap limited the impact of the voting initially, then all of the fraudulent votes went away when they were reversed.

As BoltClock said, your user history shows that your highest-ever rep until today was 6856. You had a quick spike thanks to the upvotes, but you simply dropped back to where you were. (Meta shows 7056 currently due to caching.)

Comment: It seems I really have misremembered my total reputation. Sorry for the misleading title. Thanks. :)